# How to show that for matrix function $Q$ we have $(Q^{-1})'=-Q^{-1}Q'Q^{-1}$?

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives

Let $Q(t)=[q_{ij}(t)]$ be an $n\times n$ matrix where the entries are functions of $t$.

How do we derive the relationship $(Q^{-1})'=-Q^{-1}Q'Q^{-1}$?

I'm doing problems related to calculus of matrix functions.

I've shown relationships such as $(PQ)'=PQ'+P'Q$.

I initially tried to use a formula for inverse matrix that uses cofactors

$$Q^{-1}=\frac{C^T}{\det{Q}}=\frac{1}{\det{Q}}[c_{ij}^T]=\frac{1}{\det{Q}}[c_{ji}]$$

$$(Q^{-1})'=\frac{1}{\det{A}}[c_{ij}'^T]$$

This path seems not to work. I think I am just missing the relevant formula for inverse matrix that I can then differentiate to obtain the desired result.

Comment: Should your product rule be $(PQ)' = PQ' + P'Q$?

Comment: Corrected the typos.

Answer (score 1):

Using the product rule
$$ (PQ)' = PQ' + P'Q$$
which you mention in your post, you can find the claimed formula by differentiating
$$ Q^{-1} Q = \operatorname{Id}.$$
Indeed, by the product rule and the fact that the derivative of the identity matrix is 0 we get
$$Q^{-1}Q' + (Q^{-1})'Q = 0\tag{1},$$
so your formula follows by rearranging (1).